# Way to get the sum property values of an object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, sum

I'd like to get the sum of object properties

Here is my Input

```
{
    "Obj1": {
        "1": 50,
        "2": 45.5,
        "3": 15,
        "4": 10,
        "5": 20
    },   
    "Obj2": {
        "1": 12.5,
        "2": 0,
        "3": 0,
        "4": 12.5,
        "5": 0
    }
}
```

Want my output to be

```
Obj1 = 140.5          
Obj2 = 25
```

Let me know if there is a way to get the output as mentioned above  in javascript

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Any reason why you use those `{"1": value, "2": value, ...}` objects instead of arrays?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your use case:

```js
const data = {
    "Obj1": { "1": 50, "2": 45.5, "3": 15, "4": 10, "5": 20 },
    "Obj2": { "1": 12.5, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 12.5, "5": 0 },
};

const sums = {};
for (const key in data) {
    sums[key] = Object.values(data[key]).reduce((tot, v) => tot + v, 0);
}
console.log(sums);
// {
//     "Obj1": 140.5,
//     "Obj2": 25
// }
```

Mind that with your sequential keys for your sub-objects, it might be better to use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using Object.assign and reduce to create one object with the key/value pairs that correspond with your desired result.

```js
const data = {
  "Obj1": { "1": 50, "2": 45.5, "3": 15, "4": 10, "5": 20 },
  "Obj2": { "1": 12.5, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 12.5, "5": 0 },
};
const result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(data).map(e => ({[e[0]]: Object.entries(e[1]).reduce((b,a) => b+a[1],0)})))
console.log(result)
```